# How to display data of multiple Columns in one richtextbox in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to display multiple entries in a single richtextbox. But not in a datagridview. Just in a simple flow with next line. I have tried this code it just show entries from first column.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT phonetic,grammar, meaning, sentence FROM dictionaryTable WHERE word LIKE'" + this.WakhiWordRTB.Text.Trim() + "'", con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
try {
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        EnglishMeningRTB.Text = dr.GetString('phonetic') & Environment.NewLine & 
        dr.GetString('grammar') & Environment.NewLine & dr.GetString('meaning') & 
        Environment.NewLine & dr.GetString('sentece') }
    else
    {
        EnglishMeningRTB.Text = "Sorry no such word found!! Try different word";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: change `&` to `+`

Comment: Has anyone advised you to take a look at http://Bobby-Tables.com yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mingling SQL, vb.net and c# in this line:

```
EnglishMeningRTB.Text = dr.GetString('phonetic') & Environment.NewLine & 
       dr.GetString('grammar') & Environment.NewLine & dr.GetString('meaning') & 
         Environment.NewLine & dr.GetString('sentece') }
```

and I'm surprised at your assertion that you "only get the first character" because it shouldn't even compile. I'd expect the line that sets your text to look more like:

```
EnglishMeningRTB.Text = $"{dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("phonetic"))}\r\n   {dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("grammar"))}\r\n{dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("meaning"))\r\n{dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("sentece"))}";
```

Or this if you're on pre c#6:

```
EnglishMeningRTB.Text = string.Format(
  "{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}\r\n{3}",
  dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("phonetic")),
  dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("grammar")),
  dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("meaning")),
  dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("sentence"))
);
```

I've never known `datareader.GetString()` to accept a string name of a column; afaik it takes an integer column ordinal that must be looked up using `GetOrdinal()`

If you're looking to format your text so that the definition is in bold, grammar in italics etc you'll need to format RTF text and set the .Rtf property instead of the .Text property

In line with my comment above and also in addition to the fact that writing database access code this way is ugly as sin, I recommend you at least look at Dapper, if not EF. With Dapper your code could look more like:

```
//make a strongly typed class to represent your dictionary entry
public class Definition{
  public string Phonetic {get; set;}
  public string Grammar {get; set;}
  public string Meaning {get; set;}
  public string Sentence {get; set;}
  public override ToString(){
    return $"{Phonetic}\r\n{Grammar}\r\n{Meaning}\r\n{Sentence}";
  }
}

//in your windows form, something like this gets your db entry, converts it to an instance of the Definiton class, disposes the connection etc:
using (var db = DapperConnectionFactory())
{
  var wordDef = db.QueryFirstOrDefault<Definition>("SELECT phonetic,grammar,meaning,sentence FROM dictionaryTable WHERE word LIKE @word", _wahkiWordRtb.Trim());

  EnglishMeningRTB.Text = wordDef?.ToString() ?? "Word not found";
}
```

Nicer, safer, easier to read and write, more maintainable, quicker...

https://dapper-tutorial.net/

Comment: Also it is `sentence` in the SQL Select and `sentece` in the `DataReader` access.  Clearly it is fake code